# Neural Network mistakes catching

Tags: python, neural-network

I'm trying to understand code i found in github. I'm new to neural networking and I'm stuck.
How do i modify code:...

```
def test(model, device, test_loader):
    model.eval()
    test_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    mistakes = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for data, target in test_loader:
            data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
            output = model(data)
            test_loss += F.nll_loss(output, target, reduction='sum').item()  # sum up batch loss
            pred = output.argmax(dim=1, keepdim=True)  # get the index of the max log-probability
            correct += pred.eq(target.view_as(pred)).sum().item()

    test_loss /= len(test_loader.dataset)

    print('\nTest set: Average loss: {:.4f}, Accuracy: {}/{} ({:.0f}%)\n'.format(
        test_loss, correct, len(test_loader.dataset),
        100. * correct / len(test_loader.dataset)))
```

...To display mistakes like?

**print('This is the true label => ', true_label)**

**print('This is my predicted label => ', pred_label)**

Answer (score 0):

`target` is a true label and `pred` is a predicted label. You decide whether you want to print them on every loop or do it the other way around.

Comment: Thank you, It seems you are right. I am getting vectors with normalized data.
If you only were so kind and could tell me how do i convert these vectors to the digits like (6,4,9)?

`print('target => ', target, ' pred => ', pred)`

Comment: There is a lot of missing information, but: I suppose you're using one-hot encoding on MNIST dataset. `output.argmax()` solves this problem, as this func returns the index of the largest probability, therefore you should get your class.